# getting a string between two strings not in the same line, regex

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript I'm trying to get everything in between this two strings
however the content I want to get is not in the same line and I'm getting it from an api.

When I make the call I get this as a string

```
the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

BlogPostStart

the 1960s with the release of L
etraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
passages, and more recently with desktop
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 
including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

BlogEnd
```

Basically I have to get everything between BlogPostStart and BlogEnd without those two words included or the top part.

I tried this post is the whole string from the api, basically whats up there:

```
var blogDescription = post.match(/^(?!\s*(BlogPost|EndBlog)).*/gmi);
```

but it just return every line in an array format.

Comment: Would something like this work: http://regexr.com/3fs8m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`babel-plugin-transform-dotall-regexp`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/babel-plugin-transform-dotall-regex) to enable the proposed `s` flag to make the dot match everything, then write

```
/BlogPostStart(.*)BlogEnd/is
                           ^ Use the new "s" flag.
```

Your result will be found in the capture group:

```
console.log(text.match(regexp)[1]);
```

As of this writing this [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-dotall-flag) is currently at stage 3 of the TC39 process, and not yet implemented in any engines to my knowledge. It is also supported by the [XRegExp package](http://xregexp.com/api/).

Or just use `[^]`:

```js
const text = `the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

BlogPostStart

the 1960s with the release of L
etraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
passages, and more recently with desktop
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 
including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

BlogEnd`;

console.log(text.match(/BlogPostStart\s*([^]*)\s*BlogEnd/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, React doesn't have anything with that. It's just plain old JavaScript... with regex, of course =)

```js
var string = "the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing <br/>\
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop <br/>\
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker <br/>\
including versions of Lorem Ipsum. <br/>\
<br/>\
BlogPostStart \
\
the 1960s with the release of L <br/>\
etraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum<br/>\
passages, and more recently with desktop<br/>\
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker <br/>\
including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br/><br/>\
Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. <br/>\
Nullam volutpat risus nec leo commodo, ut interdum diam laoreet. Sed non consequat odio. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Viva Forevis aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent.<br/>\
<br/>\
BlogEnd";


// REGEX ===============================================================
// =====================================================================
var result = string.match(/(?:BlogPostStart)([\s\S]*)(?:BlogEnd)/)
// =====================================================================
// =====================================================================

document.write(!!result && result[1].trim());
```